# Visual studio me subrraya en amarillo sc del scanner y no se porque

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente codigo aunque perfectamente podria ser cualquier otro codigo ya que me pasa con todos los que utilizo el Scanner

```
package ejercicios.Obligatoria2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PROG02_EJER4{

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int intro;
        System.out.println("introduce tu edad a continuacion");
        intro = sc.nextInt();
        while (intro < 18){
            System.out.println("Es menor de edad");
            break;
        }
        while (intro >18){
            System.out.println("Es mayor de edad");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

el problema que tengo es que en este punto:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

el "sc" en el visual studio code y en otros IDE me lo surrayan en amarillo y me dice que para solucionarlo rode el codigo de "try" osea segun visual studio quedaria asi:

```
package ejercicios.Obligatoria2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PROG02_EJER4{

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int intro;
            System.out.println("introduce tu edad a continuacion");
            intro = sc.nextInt();
            while (intro < 18){
                System.out.println("Es menor de edad");
                break;
            }
            while (intro >18){
                System.out.println("Es mayor de edad");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Me podria decir alguien porque pasa esto y porque visual estudio lo soluciona con "try" ya que no se exactamente para que sirve el try y como y en que puntos se usa
Gracias

PD: ya se que si pusiese un if para hacer la condicion de:

```
while (intro < 18){
            System.out.println("Es menor de edad");
            break;
        }
        while (intro >18){
            System.out.println("Es mayor de edad");
            break;
```

me quedaria mas limpio pero el ejercicio que tengo consiste en hacerlo sin el if

Comment: Y fuiste a la documentacion de Java a ver que hace try--catch?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te lo marca en amarillo debido a que estas teniendo un leak de recursos, es decir, no estas cerrando el scanner. Para solucionarlo debes utilizar el metodo [.close()](https://linuxhint.com/close-scanner-in-java/).

El IDE te lo esta resolviendo con un try, específicamente, el tipo de try que te esta recomendando se llama [try-with-resources](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/try-with-resources-feature-in-java/). Lo que hace es cerrar de forma automática el recurso declarado dentro de los paréntesis. De esta forma te evitas escribir el .close() al terminar de utilizar tu recurso puesto que se infiere que una vez termine de ejecutarse el código dentro del bloque del try se cerrara automáticamente.